# Sending context data with POST request

Tags: python, django, payment-gateway

I am trying to add a payment gateway to my website. I have a 'Pay now' button has 'href' attribute to the view which handles the payment. This view provides all the varuables needed by the gateway to process the request. In the end of the view, I redirect the user to the payment gateway page with the variables being passed in the `RequestContext`. How do I send them as a form fiels to the payment gateway site?

Here is my view to  handle the checkout:

```
import hashlib

def redirect(request):
    basket = request.basket
    key = 'to be provided by payu'
    txnid = basket.id,
    amount = basket.total_incl_tax
    phash = hashlib.sha(str(key)+'|'+str(txnid))
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
        'hash' : phash.hexdigest(),
        'key' : key,
        'txnid': txnid,
        'amount' : amount,
    })
    return HttpResponseRedirect('https://test.payu.in/_payment', variables)
```

So, basically my question is, is it possible to send the above `variables` in a POST request to the url `https://test.payu.in/_payment`? If not, then what are the alternatives?

Comment: I think you want to make a post request? If you are redirecting, you lose all context.

Comment: Can that be done from a view?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, dont name your function **redirect** it is already taken. So here i am using django's redirect:

One way would be to pass variables in url. Here just a pseudo example...

```
return redirect('https://test.payu.in/_payment?k=%s&h=%s', % ( key, hash))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you faced such problem there's slight chance that you had over-complicated your design.

This is a restriction of HTTP that POST data cannot go with redirects.

If you really need to redirect in a POST request try it in client side using JavaScript.